# How to unpack two points with \foreach

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach

Some one could explain why this unpacking rule does not work?

```
    \foreach \x / \y in {(2.0,3.0) / (2.0,5.0), (2.0,3.0) / (2.0,5.0), (2.0,3.0) / (2.0,5.0)}
    {
        \draw \x -- \y;   
    }
```

Comment: I guess the commas in the pairs confuse the parser.

Comment: Put the coordinates between braces, to hide the commas.

Comment: @egreg The commas in the second coordinate of each pair are problematic. The commas in the first are OK as the parser has special handling for this case. (Page 902 of the manual.)

Comment: Code golfing: `\draw(2,3)--(2,5);` :-)

Comment: BTW, hopefully, the lines are not connected, otherwise the line connection is not handled by parameter `line join`. Depending on the angle and line width, the line connections do not look to good. In any case, the example can be optimized for the output by putting `\foreach` inside `\draw`: `\draw \foreach ... in ... {\x -- \y};`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The special handling of coordinates only applies where the first character in an item is a `(`. In that case, everything up until the first `)` is read as part of one value. So the coordinates before the `/` are OK, but those after the `/` need to be enclosed in curly brackets. (See page 902 of the manual.)

In addition, the parser doesn't seem to like some of the spaces and you need something like the following.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \foreach \x / \y in {(2.0,3.0)/{(2.0,5.0)}, (2.0,3.0)/{(2.0,5.0)}, (2.0,3.0)/{(2.0,5.0)}}
  {
    \draw \x -- \y;
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```